# admin template asp.net forms ready

Tags: asp.net, templates

When creating a new website in vs 2010, it provide a template with a master page, login page, register ... Is there a place where one can purchase/download asp.net ready templates?

I know themeforest has some awesome admin templates, but it's a lot of work to convert them to  masterpage and so on. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really off-topic, but the short answer is "Yes" - although I don't know that people commonly purchase them.

For example:

- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/
- http://www.templatemonster.com/
- http://www.wix.com/sample/website

Answer (score -1):

Here I am sharing an article having a collection of ready-made asp.net templates. You can also make changes if required as it's easy to make changes on ready-made templates. Check it [here](https://themeselection.com/10-best-mvc5-asp-net-core-bootstrap-admin-template).